# How can I make multiple If statement work?

Tags: mysql

I have a syntax that is working well with just single IF statement and then I decided to check the ISBN if it is already exists and if does exists it will just else return "already exists"

And I'm using the "function"

Here is what i have already tried.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ISBN FROM book WHERE ISBN=i) THEN
RETURN "Book already exists.";

ELSE
IF (b=0)
THEN
INSERT INTO book(ISBN,title,author,publisher,Date_Published,`Cost`)        VALUES(i,t,a,p,STR_TO_DATE(d, '%M %e,%Y'),c);
RETURN "Book has been successfully added.";
ELSE
UPDATE book SET ISBN=i, title=t,author=a,publisher=p,Date_Published=d,cost=c     WHERE bookID=b;
RETURN "Book has been successfully altered.";
END IF;
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi ahh missed that, you are correct : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ISBN FROM book WHERE ISBN=i) THEN
  RETURN "Book already exists."; 
ELSEIF (b=0) THEN
   INSERT INTO book(ISBN,title,author,publisher,Date_Published,`Cost`)
   VALUES(i,t,a,p,STR_TO_DATE(d, '%M %e,%Y'),c);
   RETURN "Book has been successfully added.";
ELSE
   UPDATE book SET ISBN=i,  
   title=t,author=a,publisher=p,Date_Published=d,cost=c     
   WHERE bookID=b;
   RETURN "Book has been successfully altered.";
END IF;
```

(*You need to remove the space between ELSE IF*)